# Find all issues saying `require API level` in Intellij / Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I want find all issues saying call requires some API level in whole project.

> Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19):
>   android.content.res.Resources#getDrawable

I could see its issue id is **`Issue id: NewApi`**. But I can not find a inspection name for same. Basically I want **run inspection by name** to get all these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the name in `Settings -> Inspections` (there is no filter by id, though)

In your case it's `Calling new methods on older versions`.

Answer (score 0):

**its very Simple**

1. In Android Studio `Right click` over any class file.
2. Select `Analyze` and select `Inspect Code`
3. Under the Popup window select the hierarchy like `Whole Project`, `Module App` 
   or specific file.
4. Click `OK`

it will generate the report, by this report you can find all locations of implementation.

Comment: Perhaps I mentioned `run inspection by name` in my question. I needed that for only versions issue. See @Sergey answer. Thanks for answer.